# How to get handle of the legend of a plot generated through plotyy when importing a fig file?

Tags: matlab

So my figures are here: http://www.atmos.uw.edu/~akchen0/CERES_Project/

I'd like to get the handle of the legend of the figure here so that I can copy the figure's legend entries when replotting the legend on a subplot.

If I try to find the axes by running `findobj(ax1,'Type','axes','Tag','legend')` though, it just returns an Empty matrix: 0-by-1. Is there another way to get the legend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setup is like this. First the figure is created. This one servs as a canvas. Then the other objects are drawn upon the figure. The objects drawn is called children. The function call,

```
plot(0:10);
```

Creates a figure and one child. The child is called an `axes`. By adding a legend with,

```
legend('This is a legend');
```

matlab creates an axes object named `legend` an places it in the figure. This becomes another child. The object handles to the children can be found in

```
 h = get(gcf,'Children')
```

Then you may save the figure and close it down. When you are loading the figure again, the whole figure, with legends and so on is restored. This includes giving the children new object handles. This means that the children can again be retrieved with,

```
 h = get(gcf,'Children')
```

you can find the child properties with

```
get(h(anyElementInChButJustOnePerCall))
```

By looking at the properties, you will notice that there is a porperty called `Tag`. This one is named `legend` for the legend. You can find it with `get` and look through the properties for all handles (should not be too many) or automatically with a `for` loop

```
h = get(hFig,'children');
hLeg = [];
for k = 1:length(h)
    if strcmpi(get(h(k),'Tag'),'legend')
        hLeg = h(k);
        break;
    end
end
```

Where hFig is the handle of the figure (written in the upper right "Figure..."). Or if the figure is just loaded it can be accessed with "get current figure" `gcf`.

Comment: Okay cool - thanks very much! I tried that solution and it did give me a legend, though it gave me a bunch of extra legend entries too, as shown below at http://puu.sh/8SpPe.png . Do you know how I could eliminate all those extra legend entries?

Comment: Ok you need to do some research by yourself here, look at the children and see what you have. For a single plot with a legend entry, you should only get a single legend axes. I am not sure how it works for subplot, but I assume that the number of legend axes should be that same as the number of plots where you have defined a legend. Anyway, the row on line 272 does not even run on my matlab version. The command that I use is 'set(hLeg2,'String',get(hLeg,'String'))'. There are of course a number of thing that is uncertain. Eg number of legends in hLeg must be equal to number of lines in fig2.

Answer (score 6):

Your mistake was, that you used the axes handle instead of the figure handle:

```
leg = findobj(figureHandle,'Type','axes','Tag','legend')
```

or simply:

```
leg = findobj(gcf,'Tag','legend')
```

will work.

Comment: This was certainly shorter than my example +1