# add legend matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, addition, legend

I have a matlab function `myfunction(var1,var2)` which gives me a plot with a legend. I would like to generate more plots with this function in one graph. This works so far i.e. for 2 plots in one graph with:

```
myfunction(a,b)
hold on
myfunction(c,d)
hold off
```

The problem here is that the legend which is generated for each plot with:

```
legend(sprintf('%s%s',var1,' on ',var2))
legend('boxoff')
```

is only appearing for the last instance of `myfunction` (in this case with `myfunction(c,d)`, there would be only one line of legend where it says 'c on d', but I would like to have two lines with 'a on b' and 'c on d')

So how can I add something to the legend without overwriting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility is to use the [dynamic legend](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/legend-semi-documented-feature) (not so-well documented) feature of MATLAB. In your case, instead of passing the legend captions to the `legend` function, you'll need to use them as input arguments to the `plot` function:

```
plot(x, y, 'DisplayName', 'caption');
```

and then add the legend using the following syntax:

```
lh = legend('-DynamicLegend');
set(lh, 'Box', 'off');
```

However, I wouldn't suggest this approach if you have a large number of graphs to be rendered on the same plot as fast as possible, e.g. in a loop. In these cases the dynamic legend might cause a significant performance hit.

Comment: Thanks,  it works just as I wanted it to with this code

Comment: Just one additonal question. It works so far with the code
plot(x, y, 'DisplayName', sprintf('%s%s_{%.1f}',a,b,c));
But I would like to add text in the form
sprintf('%s%s_{%.1f}',a,' on ',b,c)
This does not work and the legend becomes a mess. What can I do against it

Comment: @Manuel I think there is something wrong in this: `sprintf('%s%s_{%.1f}',a,' on ',b,c)`. The _signature_ of `sprintf` is: `sprintf(pattern, var1, var2, ...)`. in your code there are 3 format specifiers with 4 variables (`a`, `b`, `c` and `' on '`).

Comment: Hm, it works so far also with sprintf('%s%s',a,' on ',b)
' on ' is a word which is then printed. a and b are the variables. It does not work anymore, when I would like to add the variable c as underscore to b but I do not know why.

Comment: @Manuel Even if it works, it's not correct to call `sprintf` with a pattern string that doesn't contain as many format specifiers as the variables given to the function. In your case, you should also add to the `pattern` string one format specifier for the `c` variable. I would rewrite  `sprintf('%s%s',a,' on ',b)` as `sprintf('%s on %s', a, b)`, which is equivalent. If you want to display also `c`, assuming you want it formatted as string: `sprintf('%s on %s, %s', a, b, c)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. sprintf('%s on %s, %s', a, b, c) works. I did not know that I could write a string in the first half of the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be doing this a lot it might be best to export the legend labels as an output argument of your function, then concatenate them and call `legend` outside the function.

If it's just a hack then inside your function you could look at the axis handle and pull the legend entries out. There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23737080/1770618) that does that.

Comment: Thanks, but it is just for a couple of plots. When I have more, I will try that.